# Given $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, Is there exist a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A$ only have $x$ as the null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Given $x\in \mathbb{R}^n,x\ne 0$, Is there exist a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A$ has the null space that only expanded by $x$. Namely,

$$Ax=0$$
$$Ay\ne 0, (y\ne cx)$$

Intuitively, matrix $A$ exists, but how can we construct it? I think this problem contains two parts. First, we should prove that $A$ exists. Then we should show how to construct the matrix $A$.

Comment: Hint: The case $x=0$ is trivial. If $x\ne 0$, extend $(x)$ to a basis $\mathbb{e}$ of $\mathbb R^n$, e.g. $\mathbb{e}=(x, e_2, e_3,\ldots, e_n)$. Make a linear operator $L$ that maps $x$ to $0$, all the other $e_i$'s to themselves. In the basis $\mathbb{e}$, the matrix of the operator $L$ is a diagonal matrix with $0,1,1,\ldots,1$ on the diagonal. Find the matrix of the operator in the canonical basis - this gives you the matrix $A$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop you assume $x\not\in \mathbb{R}e_1$, right?

Comment: @ThomasPreu What is $e_1$? My extension of the linearly independent set $(x)$ to the basis with vectors $e_2,e_3,\ldots,e_n$ uses indexes $2,3,\ldots,n$. I am *not* implying that $e_2,e_3,\ldots,e_n$ come from the *canonical* basis - they are just *an extension*. Maybe I should've called them $v_2,v_3,\ldots,v_n$ - would that be less ambiguous?

Comment: @StinkingBishop yes, indeed, I assumed you referred to the standard basis. Your clarification helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x = 0$, it suffices to take an invertible matrix $A$ (such as the identity matrix). So, I will consider only the case where $x \neq 0$.

One convenient way to construct a suitable matrix is to use an orthogonal projection matrix. In particular, given the non-zero vector $x$ of interest, take
$$
A = I - \frac{xx^T}{x^Tx},
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Note that for a vector $y$, $Ay$ is the component of $y$ orthogonal to $x$. So, $Ay = 0 \iff y = cx$ for some $c \in \Bbb R$.

For a more rigorous argument that doesn't rely on an understanding of orthogonality, consider the following.
\begin{align}
Ay = 0 &\implies \left(I - \frac{xx^T}{x^Tx} \right)y = 0
\\ &\implies y - \frac{x(x^Ty)}{x^Tx} = 0
 \implies y = \frac{x^Ty}{x^Tx} \cdot x.
\end{align}
so, if $Ay = 0$, then $y = cx$ with $c = \frac{x^Ty}{x^Tx}$. Conversely, if $y = cx$, then
$$
Ay = cx - \frac{x(x^T(cx))}{x^Tx} = cx - c\cdot \frac{x^Tx}{x^Tx} \cdot x = 0.
$$

Comment: It's amazing. I hadn't imagined it looks so nice. May I know how you come across this? Just wonder is there any specific name for this construction?

Comment: I came across it by writing a dissertation about linear algebra. $A$ is an example of an [orthogonal projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections).

Answer (score 2):

For $x=0$ just take the identity matrix.

For $x\neq 0$ take the vector $x$ and make it part of a basis $\mathcal{B}=\{x,v_2,…,v_n\}$. Take the matrix $$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&I_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$, which sends $x$ to 0 and all $v_i$ to themselves. Then
$$A=D_\mathcal{SB}BD_\mathcal{BS}$$
does the job, where $\mathcal{S}=\{e_1,…,e_n\}$ denotes the standard basis and $D_\mathcal{BS}$ is the change of coordinate matrix from standard basis to the chosen basis $\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One way to generate such an A is as follows:

Take the first column of an $n\times n$-matrix $T$ to be $x$ and choose arbitrary $n-1$ other vectors for the remaining columns such that they form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - e.g. they can be chosen as $n-1$ vectors from the $n$ standard basis vectors $e_i$. Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with only $1$ in the diagonal except for $D_{1,1}=0$. Then $A=TDT^{-1}$ will do or even just $A=DT^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x\in\Bbb{R^n}\setminus \{0\}$ ( otherwise it's trivial)

Let $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) $ and suppose $x_i\neq 0$ for some $1\le i\le n$

Then consider the matrix $A\in M_n(\Bbb{R})$ such that

$\operatorname{rref}A =\begin{pmatrix} e_1,\ldots,e_{i-1},-N_i,e_{i+1},\ldots,e_n\end{pmatrix}$

Where $e_i$ is the $i$-th column vector of identity matrix and

$N_i=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x_1}{x_i}\\ \vdots\\ \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}\\0\\\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}\\\vdots\\ \frac{x_n}{x_i}\end{pmatrix}$

Null space basis is $\{\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x_1}{x_i}\\ \vdots\\ \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}\\1\\\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}\\\vdots\\ \frac{x_n}{x_i}\end{pmatrix}\}$

Then it is clear that $Ax=0$ as $x$ is $x_i$ times basis vector and $\operatorname{rref}A$ has exactly $n-1$ pivot columns .Null space is $1$-dimensional and $0\neq x\in \operatorname{null}(A) $ . Isn't it enough to conclude $\operatorname{null}(A)= \textrm{span}\{x\}$ ?

Hence $\operatorname{null}(A) =\textrm{span}\{x\}$

---

Note: Choose the matrix  $\operatorname{rref}A$ or any matrix whose reduced row echelon form is of the above form to get a one dimensional null space form by a specific vector.

---

**Example $1$**:

Let $n=2 $ and we want a matrix whose null space is spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$

Then choose $A$ such that $\operatorname{rref}A=\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{-1}{2}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Then null space basis is $\{\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$

Then null space is also spanned by $\{2\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$

---

**Example** $2$: Find a $3×3$ matrix whose null space is spanned by $\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\5\end{pmatrix}\}$.

Answer: $N_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{5}\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Then $A=\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&\frac{-1}{5}\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\}$

$\begin{align}\operatorname{null}(A) &=\textrm{span}\{  \begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{5}\\1\end{pmatrix} \}\\&=\textrm{span}\{  \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\5\end{pmatrix} \}\end{align}$